# Is there any way to capture screenshot --only on failure of steps in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE

Is it possible to take a screenshot for each failed step using Selenium IDE

Is there any way to do this.

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

It very helpful to make screenshots while test executes and the is one command.It not very usible, but it works)

**captureEntirePageScreenshot(filename, kwargs)**
    Arguments:
     filename - the path to the file to persist the screenshot as. No filename extension will be appended by default. Directories will not be created if they do not exist, and an exception will be thrown, possibly by native code.
     kwargs - a kwargs string that modifies the way the screenshot is captured. Example: "background=#CCFFDD" . Currently valid options:

You should create some jpeg file before.For example my command looks like:

**captureEntirePageScreenshot** //command name;
arguments:
C:\Users\Anna\Desktop\tests_screenshots\133.jpg  //path to jpeg file (filename), 
background#CCFFDD // argument by default

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was wondering the same thing just today and found the following:

http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/examples/capturing-screenshots-from-remote-selenium-rc/